# What is the impact of accepting the shift of role from a core developer to a white box tester?

Tags: career-development, job-change, careers, career-switch, developer

I am C# and .net developer with about 5 years of experience. I'm considering the shift of my role from a core developer to a white box tester.

1. What would be the impact on my career as developer?
2. In the long run, would I be considered as a tester?
3. What are the pros and cons of it?

Comment: In general, this is seen as a demotion.

Comment: Flagged for opinion based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be absolutely sure you want to be a tester before you make that switch.  After a few years away from software development it will be extremely difficult to go back.  It would be like working in software maintenance with some legacy language/technology for years and then trying to get a dev role using the latest stuff (actually, it would be worse than that).

In regards to your second question - yes, after doing testing for a while, you will be considered a Test Engineer (or some equivalent title).  In other words, yes, this is a career change, you would be leaving software development to become a tester.

Now, testing isn't a dead end -- at companies I've worked for testers can become leads of a test team (esp. on large programs), QA manager, etc.

Personally I wouldn't do it, but I have known Software developers that transitioned to 'Test Engineer' and loved it.  I've also met one that tried it for a few months and then ran away screaming.  It probably depends on your personality and what type of work suits you.

A good tester is a great resource to have, as much as I may get frustrated with them :) If you love writing and/or following processes/procedures, are extremely detail-oriented, and enjoy making devs angry, then testing might be for you.

Comment: I am not doing pure development in my current project and its not helping much for my career.So,if I take up white box testing with C#,.net where in I would be doing coding and touch with the technology, would it be a good decision?

Comment: @AmritaS I was wondering if you could throw some light on how do you find this new profile (if you had accepted that role of Test engineer). Thank you